# Bash script to display CNAME chains in a zone file

Tags: bash, dns

I'm trying to write a bash script that will give me the output in file for chained CNAME records in a zone file. I've managed to make only one step chain (cname1 CNAME cname2 -> cname2 -> some A record).

What I'm trying to do is to print out the whole chain if there are multiple steps in between.

> chainA          A       10.100.250.22 
>  
>   chainB          CNAME   chainA 
>   chainC          CNAME   chainB 
>   chainD             CNAME   chainC

I'd like to have output like:
chainD -> chainC -> chainB -> chainA is A record.

So far, I have all the cnames extracted into one file and a while loop that iterates through them, but it only finds one step:

```
#!/bin/bash
    read -e -p "Enter filename (use tab for completion): " file
    ls -l "$file"
    date=$(date +%m_%d_%y)
    echo $date
    if [ -f chained_cnames_$date ] ; then
        rm chained_cnames_$date
    fi
    grep -w "CNAME" $file | grep "^[^#;]" > cnames_out
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
    do
      echo "Scanning record: $line"
      name=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[.].*$//' | awk '{$1=$1};1')
      dst=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/[.].*$//' | awk '{$1=$1};1')
      dst_long=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
      dst_long_a=$(dig +noall +answer $dst_long | awk '{print $1}')
      if [ "$name" = "$dst" ]
      then
        ipaddr="$(dig $dst_long +short)"
        if [ -z "$ipaddr" ]
        then
          echo $line "   --->   "  "NO A RECORD"  >> chained_cnames_$date
        else
          echo $line "   --->   "  $ipaddr "  A record exists, but is not in this zone file.\n It should be like:\n $name   CNAME   $dst_long_a" >> chained_cnames_$date
        fi
      else
        while IFS='' read -r line1 || [[ -n "$line1" ]]
        do
          testrec=$(echo $line1 | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{$1=$1};1')
          if [ "$dst" = "$testrec" ]
          then
            echo >> chained_cnames_$date
            echo $line " ---> " $line1 >> chained_cnames_$date
            echo >> chained_cnames_$date
         fi
        done < "cnames_out"
      fi
    done < "cnames_out"
    echo
    echo
    echo "Done! Invalid records are stored in the chained_cnames_$date file."
    rm cnames_out
```

How to I create such a loop?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, this is my first post...

Comment: oh, ouch, This is why you need to include you code. So Good Show for updating your Q. Almost certainly this could be done as 1 awk script. Also, seems like reading `man tsort` might be of help for  you. If it can't be done as 1 awk script, at least reduce items like `name=$(awk | sed | awk)` to `name=$(awk '{sub(s/[.].*$/,"",$1);$1=$1}1' <<< "$line"`! .Recall that `awk` can execute multiple statements AND that is has `sub` and `gsub` (and `gensub`) substitution functions.  It's the middle of the night here, I'll look again tomorrow to see if I can help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to work something out with tsort, also tnx for the variable shortening suggestion, I'll incorporate that too as soon as I get somewhere with the loops. :). I'll actually try to reduce this like:
`example1 cname example2
example2 cname example3`
and then just checking where example3 leads with dig, and output the suggestion record
`example1 CNAME example2 should be: example1 CNAME [A_record_output_from_dig_+answer]`

Comment: OK, glad you're getting something from this. But rather than try to explain in comments, please improve your Q above including sample input of data that should be processed, and other data that should not be processed (passed thru/deleted?) the expected output from that input and your code. I still think a complete rewrite in awk is really the way to go. will help you if you want to do that (and have the time;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: The only worthwhile man page in the google top 5 is at https://ss64.com/bash/tsort.html . More helpfully, see wikipedia for `tsort Linux`. Good luck.

Comment: In your revised sample data, please indicate if each block can be a variable length, or if they are always 4 lines long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a little fun,

```
% cat cNamePath.sh

#!/bin/bash
# chainA A 10.100.250.22
# chainB CNAME chainA
# chainC CNAME chainB
# chainD CNAME chainC

awk '
  NR!=1{print $1 " " $3}
' ./testDat.raw | {
  tsort | tr '\n' ' '
  # process inFile a 2nd time, just to grab the first record
  # this could be simplified to just a `print` statment, do you see how? ;-)
  awk 'NR==1{base=$1;skip=$2;ip=$3;print base " is A record"}' ./testDat.raw
}
% chmod +x cNamePath.sh
```

**output**

```
chainD chainC chainB chainA chainA is A record
```

If you really need output with `->`, I'm sure you can figure out how to get it. 
Also, you'll need to parameterize passing in the filename.

To understand how the code is working, execute the first "pipe-full", and then add another section, and another, etc.

The closing `| { tsort ... ; awk ..; }` is called a process group (denoted by the matched pair `{ ..}`. You use this so all output is "folded together" and delivered to the same "target". If you want to redirect the output to a file, using the process group makes it real easy, i.e. `...| {tsort ... ; awk ...;} > outFile` (I include a `;` char to show that cmd is stand-alone and is not sent in a pipe to the following cmd. It is not included in the code, because the line break between the `tsort` line and the `nawk` line function in the same way as `;` does on a single line. (TMI?)

If you don't know about `tsort`, check out this [linux tsort on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsort) article.

The beauty of `tsort` is that it will figure out the order of relations for you, you don't need a "sorted" file as you have provided., it can just as easily order data like

```
chainA A 10.100.250.22
chainD CNAME chainC
chainC CNAME chainB
chainB CNAME chainA
```

IHTH

Comment: I'm still new to bash, don't know a thing about awk, but this thing WORKS!!
tnx!
P.S. and tnx for the tsort wiki, that man page is definitely worthless for such command...

Comment: Again, I encourage you to take that code apart, one statement at a time. See (and understand) what just `awk '  NR!=1{print $1 " " $3}
' ./testDat.raw` does, then add the `|` and the next cmd, etc to see what is happening. Also, get "Effective Awk Programming", it's really worth it! While you're waiting for the printed book to arrive, run the the [Grymoire Awk Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html). Glad this helped.

Comment: And of course, for your education, then consider how you could convert your original code into just one (well maybe 2) `awk` programs. (I'm guessing that writing `tsort` in `awk` wouldn't b2hard). Do you know about counting processes created in  script? Each external cmd, and `$(...)` construct requires the shell to stop, ask the OS to create a new process, copy the environment, attach std-in and std-out, (and maybe a few other things). Very "expensive" if you are processing multiple fields on a per-line basis (as you are doing above). Anyway, that may have to wait for another day. Good luck!

Comment: tnx for the advice! I'll definitely have to develop different kind of approach, over the time I guess, I'm still at some basic level of coding in general, but these kind of directions helps a lot... The way I was doing it was the only thing that I could think of at that point in time, so I guess over the time things will get better.
tnx!